# How to normalise vertex normal vector c#

Tags: c#, vector, converters, normalization

I have a binary file format with vertex positions, normals, UVs and weights.
All works fine except I can't understand how to get vertex normals out of it.
V normals are recorded as bytes (one byte per one vertex position, for instance 3 bytes for PosX, posY and posZ).
That's what I have in binary file:

```
(byte)122 (byte)225 (byte)209
```

I use an additional software to convert this binary file and it outputs me:

```
0.299055 0.712744 0.634477
```

I tried to normalize the vectors but I get incorrect results:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            posArr[i * 3 + 0] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].X;
            posArr[i * 3 + 1] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].Y;
            posArr[i * 3 + 2] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].Z;
            length = (float)Math.Sqrt((rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].normX * rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].normX) + (rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].normY * rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].normY) + (rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].normZ * rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].normZ));
            normArr[i * 3 + 0] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].normX / length;
            normArr[i * 3 + 1] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].normY / length;
            normArr[i * 3 + 2] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].normZ / length;
            cordArr[i * 2 + 0] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].U;
            cordArr[i * 2 + 1] = 1 - rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].V;
        }
```

This code outputs me:

```
0.3692057 0.6809122 0.6324918
```

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe it will help if I add vertices positions:
0.5576172 1.788086 0.1794434

Comment: Hello,

I think this is not the right place for your question (next time try this http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) , But I found something that can lead you to the solution :)

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8408/best-way-to-compute-vertex-normals-from-a-triangles-list

Comment: @pix thanks, will know

Comment: How about writing a method `Vector3 Normalize(Vector3 input)`? This code is a non-reusable mess. Also, which library is this? It's quite likely that it already has normalization methods, if it supports vector math.

Comment: @Groo it's not an XNA library so I doubt it supports Vectors and Normalize methods.
I'm writing a converter from closed binary file to .dae (xml-like) file format. I'm not using any math libs

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking at the wrong thing? Both vectors you posted are normalized (i.e. have length `1`). For vector `(122, 225, 209)` your solution is the correct one.

Comment: @Groo the vectors are probably already normalised and recorded to bytes and perhaps there's no need to normalise them but how otherwise I will get a float value outta byte? If I divide my byte on 255 I don't get correct outputs.

Comment: @MrJox Normalizing the vector means dividing it by its length, so that the normalized length is `1`. If the input vector was normalized with byte resolution, its length would have been `255`. As I wrote, your solution is the correct, normalized vector.

Comment: @Groo found a key how to decode these byes: 
"packed bytes are unsigned bytes, divide by 255.0, then times 2.0, then minus 1.0 for the actual value."
But what does it mean "then times 2.0"?

Comment: Ok, this would mean that each byte value (`0..255`) should be mapped to (`-127.5..127.5`) and then divided by `127.5` to get the (`-1..1`) range. You can do this using `x = (x - 127.5)/127.5)`, or, as you wrote `x = x/255*2 - 1 = x/127.5 - 1`. Result is still not normalized, as far as I can see.